# OSX: Crontab will not execute sh script despite using crontab -e to change settings

Tags: macos, shell, sh, cron

So i'm trying to execute a shell file called test.sh at 5PM every day. The test.sh file lives in my Desktop. After using crontab -e, this is what my crontab file looks like:

```
0    17    *    *    *    *    root    sh /Users/theuser/Desktop/test
```

Everything is separated by a tab. So the 0 is separated from the 17 by a tab, the first asterisk from the 17 by a tab, etc. etc. Is the reason why my shell isn't running a syntax error? Is it something else? thanks in advance.

One more thing: When I first did crontab -e, the document was empty. Is that normal?

Comment: Why have you got `sh` to execute your script? Start your script with a proper shebang and make it executable with `chmod +x yourScriptName`. Also, what is the `root` bit for?

Comment: What does the 4th `*` represent?  My crontab entries on OS X have 5 (not 6) time columns.  Also, what's the `root` supposed to represent?  Again, it isn't part of `man -s 5 crontab` on OS X.  Maybe you need to read the manual?

Comment: the root is what I gathered from reading other tutorials, but I really have no idea if it works or not. So what you're saying is that I should do:                                   0    17    *    *    *    * chmod _x /Users/theuser/Desktop/test ?

Comment: To the extent I'm suggesting anything, then `0 17 * * * sh /Users/theuser/Desktop/test` where the script can contain whatever you need.  The `sh` is optional; I simply use `/Users/jleffler/bin/Cron/whichevercommand` as the command name.  There is mention of `user:group` in the `man -s 5 crontab`, though I've never needed to use it (and it applies to 'the system crontab file').  When I submit the entry, it runs as me; I don't submit crontab entries for other people (unless I'm logged in as them or `su`'d or `sudo`'d to them).

Comment: could you give me a concrete example of how you would set it up? still trying to wrap my head around all this.

Comment: `crontab <<< "0 17 * * * /Users/theuser/bin/thescript"` is all it takes.  I wouldn't use a file on the desktop; I keep my scripts in `$HOME/bin`.  I have a more complex system with `$HOME/bin/cron` directory containing environment-setting scripts that then run commands in `$HOME/bin` with the same name — that's me being ... well, antiquated might be one term.  I don't trust the environment setting documented in the `crontab` man page, simply because I've never used it, because it wasn't an option when I started using `cron` (30-something years ago), and what I've got works regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first line of your script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Type the following in your Terminal to make your script executable:

```
chmod +x /Users/SomeUser/Desktop/theScript
```

Make your `crontab` like this for testing every minute

```
* * * * * /Users/SomeUser/Desktop/theScript
```

or

```
0 17 * * * /Users/SomeUser/Desktop/theScript
```

Comment: Should I do /Desktop/test.sh or just /Desktop/test ?

Comment: It doesn t matter as long as you put the same name in the crontab as however you name  the file on your Desktop - however `test` is a poor choice of name since there is another program called that.

Comment: Understood. By the way, when I first did crontab -e, I realized the document was empty. Is this normal or is there supposed to be more information in there?

Comment: It's normal that they start off empty - in fact Apple don't use, recommend or promote crontabs - they use `launchd` and `launchctl` which are more flexible.